# Regex to find all placeholder occurrences in text

Tags: c#, regex

Im struggling to create a Regex that finds all placeholder occurrences in a given text. Placeholders will have the following format:

```
[{PRE.Word1.Word2}]
```

Rules:

- Delimited by "[{PRE." and "}]" ("PRE" upper case)
- 2 words (at least 1 char long each) separated by a dot. All chars valid on each word apart from newline.
- word1: min 1 char, max 15 chars
- word2: min 1 char, max 64 chars
- word1 cannot have dots, if there are more than 2 dots inside placeholder extra ones will be part of word2. If less than 2 dots, placeholder is invalid.

Looking to get all valid placeholders regardless of what the 2 words are.

Im not being lazy, just spent an horrible amount of time building the rule on regexr.com, but was unable to cross all these rules.
Looking fwd to checking your suggestions.

The closest I've got to was the below, and any attempt to expand on that breaks all valid matches.

```
\[\{OEP\.*\.*\}\]
```

Much appreciated!

Sample text where Regex should find matches:

> Random text here
>
> [{Test}] -- NO MATCH
>
> [{PRE.TestTest3}] --NO MATCH
>
> [{PRE.TooLong.12345678901234567890}] --NO MATCH
>
> [{PRE.Address.Country}] --MATCH
>
> [{PRE.Version.1.0}] --MATCH
>
> Random text here

Comment: Can these words contain `{`, `}`, `[` or `]` chars? Well, try `\[{PRE\.([^][{}.]{1,15})\.(.{1,64}?)}]`, see [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%7bPRE%5c.%28%5b%5e%5d%5b%7b%7d.%5d%7b1%2c15%7d%29%5c.%28.%7b1%2c64%7d%3f%29%7d%5d&i=%5b%7bPRE.Word1.Word2%7d%5d+and+%5b%7bPRE.Word+3.Word.....+2+%25%25%25%7d%5d). I am not sure what output you expect, if you provide one or two test cases, I could post an answer with the code and explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Spot on! that regex seems to do the trick, if you submit as answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Jaime, I posted it [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819308/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
\[{PRE\.([^][{}.]{1,15})\.(.{1,64}?)}]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%7BPRE%5C.%28%5B%5E%5D%5B%7B%7D.%5D%7B1%2C15%7D%29%5C.%28.%7B1%2C64%7D%3F%29%7D%5D&i=%5B%7BPRE.Word1.Word2%7D%5D%20and%20%5B%7BPRE.Word%203.Word.....%202%20%25%25%25%7D%5D)

*Details*

- `\[{` - a `[{` string
- `PRE\.` - `PRE.` text
- `([^][{}.]{1,15})` - Group 1: any one to fifteen chars other than `[`, `]`, `{`, `}` and `.`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(.{1,64}?)`  - any one to 64 chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `}]` - a `}]` text.

If you need to get all matches in C#, you can use

```cs
var pattern = @"\[{PRE\.([^][{}.]{1,15})\.(.{1,64}?)}]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/DXyts3):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "[{PRE.Word1.Word2}] and [{PRE.Word 3.Word..... 2 %%%}]";
        var pattern = @"\[{PRE\.([^][{}.]{1,15})\.(.{1,64}?)}]";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
        var props = new List<Property>();
        foreach (Match m in matches)
            props.Add(new Property(m.Groups[1].Value,m.Groups[2].Value));
        
        foreach (var item in props)
            Console.WriteLine("Word1 = " + item.Word1 + ", Word2 = " + item.Word2);
    }
    
    public class Property
    {
        public string Word1 { get; set; }
        public string Word2 { get; set; }
        public Property()
        {}
        public Property(string w1, string w2)
        {
            this.Word1 = w1;
            this.Word2 = w2;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```cs
Word1 = Word1, Word2 = Word2
Word1 = Word 3, Word2 = Word..... 2 %%%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "[{PRE.Word1.Word2}]";

// language=regex
string pattern = @"\[{ PRE \. (?'group1' .{1,15}? ) \. (?'group2' .{1,64}? ) }]";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["group1"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["group2"].Value);
```

Comment: Thank you. But when getting all placeholders, I have no idea what the words are yet. Just looking to get all matches (regardless of what the words are).

Comment: @JaimeOliveira Use `Regex.Matches` instead of `Regex.Match`.

Comment: @JaimeOliveira - I changed the group names to make it clearer.

Comment: @Alexander You should make `.{1,64}` lazy too. Otherwise `[{PRE.Word1.Word2}] [{PRE.Word3.Word4}]` will be considered as one match.

Comment: What's the significance of all the spaces embedded in your pattern?  I can get your pattern to work, but only after removing the spaces.  I.E., this works for me: `@"\[{PRE\.(?'group1'.{1,15}?)\.(?'group2'.{1,64}?)}]"`

Comment: @Flydog57 You should use the regex with the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` option to ignore any whitespace inside the regex pattern (but the one inside character classes).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks.  I've never noticed that option before.  It does make it more readable.